# ruby on rails database entry matching, storage

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

This is kind of a strange question, but I will try to explain it to the best of my ability.

Let's say I have the following two tables:

```
table: cars

+---------------+------------+----------------+--------------+
|     color     |    size    |    capacity    |    origin    |
+---------------+------------+----------------+--------------+

table: users

+----------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| desired_colors | desired_sizes | desired_capacities | desired_origins |
+----------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

Obviously the cars table will consist of unique cars with color, size, capacity and origin.

In the users table, there will be user selections of multiple colors they want, multiple sizes they want, multiple capacities they want and multiple origins they want.

Now, I'm wondering the best way to achieve a 'match score' between a users desired traits and each vehicle. This way, users can see the top matches of cars that they want.

I have a few ideas on how I would do this, but I was wondering what everyone here thought was the best way to go about something like this. I'm thinking the best way is to have a 'matches' table showing a match between a `user_id`, `car_id` and a `match_score` -- but I'm not sure how and when I would run these calculations and save this data. Another thing to think about is if I decide to change the criteria for scores.

Anyways, I know this is a weird question and I might not get many answers, but just hoping to stir the pot and see if anyone has any good ideas.

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just determine my matches in a query, rather than store it in a table.  If your dataset is expected to be huge, it may be more efficient to pre-calculate matches, but in all likelihood, it would be premature optimization.  So, what I would do is load the desired features when the user logs in, then run a query such as this:

```
select *, 
if(color in ('green', 'red', blue', ...), 10, 0)
 + if(size in (...), 10, 0)
 + if(capacity in (...), 10, 0)
 + if(origin in (...), 10, 0) as score
from cars
where color in ('green', 'red', blue', ...)
or size in (...)
or capacity in (...)
or origin in (...)
```

Comment: This would work initially. Thanks for your input. If I ever need to pre calculate these matches, how could I go about that, cron?

Comment: Although, I might have to consider something a bit more sophisticated since I'm attempting to obtain a very precise score match.

Comment: Yep.  Just create a many-many mapping table that stores the relationship with a user and the cars that match, along with a score for each relationship.  Then, refresh the values in that table using a cron job.

Comment: You could always take the many-many relationship table approach and then either dynamically load it, as users log in and request the information, or populate it using a cron job.  If your formula is complex, you could take the functionality out of mysql, and write that process in ruby.  Alternatively, you could just write a user defined function in mysql that calculates the score if you'd rather keep it inside the database, which may be faster.

Comment: This seems like it's the way to go. Were expecting high volume, not sure how taxing it would be on the database but it could save us the headache to do the extra legwork. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The thing to keep in mind is that if you pre-generate it, and you have a high load, you could incur huge background processing that needs to run nightly, hourly, or whatever your schedule is.  You could use cloud computing to build a huge cluster to do all this processing on, but you'll likely need to do some optimization so that you can distribute the load and processing throughout the day. You'll also need some way to avoid pre-calculating for those users that are not logging in frequently, and perhaps just calculate matches on demand for those guys, or something along those lines.

Comment: Yeah this is going to take some fine tuning, I was afraid it would be complicated.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's best to just run it once per day, if and when the user logs in. However, the results wouldn't be instant.

Comment: That could be reasonable.  Just give the user some feedback that their matches are being calculated.

Comment: What about when a car is added, run the calculations for that car against all users and on the other end when a user is created, run that user against all cars. Would that be a good solution?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm gonna let this sit here for a little more but you'll get my accept. Thanks again!